# Parsing JSON to TextInputEditText fields

Tags: java, android, json

When device scans a barcode, I need to make a query to the SQL Table and if there is JSON data there (and there is) I have to parse JSON into Text Input Edit Text fields and brand_name into spinner, practically fill the fields for user. I'm not sure how to parse it into separate fields. Can anyone help me?

This is the JSON i have:

"count":"50",
"lot":"100620",
"brand_name":"Example",
"variant":"ZS/N 0,75 x 60",
"net_content":"20",
"unit_of_measure":"kg",
"sscc":"086060197000151569",
"sync":"NO",
"war_group_type":"123 example"

I'm very new to Java and I'm working in Android Studio, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Gson library](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) to serialize/deserialize JSON messages.

You have to create a class with the same structure that you expect for the JSON message. In your case something like:

```
public class Foo{
    public String count, lot, brand_name, variant, net_content, unit_of_measure, sync, war_group_type;
}
```

Then, considering that you have the JSON full message in a String with name `jsonString` to parse it you do like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Foo m = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Foo.class);
```

After that, you should be able to access each parameter independently:

```
Toast.makeText (getContext(), "Brand name is: " + m.brand_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Further recommendations/considerations:**

- By default, the Gson library will map the fields defined in the class to the JSON keys defined in the response. However, you can use `@SerializedName` to specify the key for a parameter instead of using the field name. One example is to define you Foo class fields like this:

  ```
   @SerializedName('brand_name')
   String brandName;
  ```
- Although it seems to not apply in your case, review how to parse list structures on link below.
- Make sure the format for every field is correct by looking at the JSON structure. For example `"count":"50",` means it should be parsed as String, while `"count":50,` can be parsed as numeric (int/long/float...).

You can find more information [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/leveraging-the-gson-library).

Comment: Thank you so much kind sir! Even though it appears a bit confusing to me atm, I'll give my best to work it out.